# How to read the plot of Quantum Kernel？

Tags: qiskit

Recently I have train a 8 qubit Quantum kernel for the 16 dimision dataset through qiskit , The quantum kernel successfully calculated the value of SVC after gradient optimization, but when I drew the graph of the quantumkernel, I found that my graph was very unintuitive.
Here I would like to ask how to read and understand the diagram of the quantum nucleus. The following are two diagrams of the quantuenter image description herem nucleus (the first one on the left is the ideal diagram of the official example, and the latter is the one I got)

"""

```
plot_data = cb_qkt.get_callback_data() 
K=optimized_kernel.evaluate(X_train)
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 20
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(14,5))
ax[0].plot([i+1 for i in range(len(plot_data[0]))],
           np.array(plot_data[2]),
           c='k',
           marker='o'
)
```

"""
Thank you for your answer！

[official example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsj7B.png)
[I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDdlo.png)

Answer (score 1):

don't know if you have found your answer yet, the graph that you show is a simple graph of correlation (kernel score) between each point of the set.

`Red` means great correlation (that's why the diagonal is `red` => each point interacts strongly with itself), `blue` means not so correlated. In your example you have two distinct group in the population. The kernel seems to be well quite fitted for discriminating those classes.